# Extra defined figures - non functional hyperref

Tags: graphics, hyperref, pdf, links

I have needed separated figures in my document and at the end of document (photos) and defined them by someone's else code. But the `pdf` hyperlinks in list of these figures are linking to title of section with these figures. 
Could you help me? Thanks.

My code (sorry for comments):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report} 
\usepackage[english, czech]{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[numbib,nottoc]{tocbibind} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}   
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}    
\usepackage[unicode,breaklinks, colorlinks=true,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\listphototitle}{Obrazové přílohy (fotodokumentace)}
\newlistof{photos}{pht}{\listphototitle}
\newcommand{\photolist}[1]{\stepcounter{photos}\addcontentsline{pht}{photos}{\protect\numberline{\thephotos}#1}}
\newcommand{\photo}[1]{\photolist{#1}{Snímek \thephotos}: #1} %name and counting before name
\cftsetindents{photos}{1.5em}{3.0em} %list indent
\setlength{\cftphotosnumwidth}{1.5cm} %numbering indent
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents{\thispagestyle{empty}} 

    \listofphotos 

\begin{minipage}[b!]{0.9\textwidth}
    \raggedright\includegraphics[width=15.5cm]{picturefile} 
    \\ \photo{Pohled pod stolovou desku -- před restaurováním} 
    \vspace{5mm} 

    \raggedright\includegraphics[width=15.5cm]{picturefile} 
    \\ \photo{Detail stolové desky -- před restaurováním} 
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your document is no document yet -- it's a fragment and not really useful for us in order to help you. Please post the minimal compilable document that has the issue you've reported. I also think that the very basic `\@cfttocstart` etc. commands are not really necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry, not it should be compilable.

Comment: We do not have `picturefile`, I'd suggest using `demo` option to `graphicx` instead, this repalces any images with black squares. Also `graphicx` can find its own drivers, so `pdftex` is not needed.

Comment: Also use `\refstepcounter` not `\stepcounter`, else the hyperlinks does not have anything to hook on to.

Comment: Guys, thank you very much! I'm just begginer in latex. I didn't knew it could be this simple.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're loading the `float` package, you might as well use its machinery to set up a new float type called (say) `photo` and a `\listofphotos` directive. Doing so will free you from having to program how to increment the counter used in photo-like floats and how to typeset the captions.  (I beg in advance for forgiveness for any mis-usage of Czech words.)

Cross-references to `photo` items may be generated using the usual LaTeX `\label`-`\ref` method. If you want to use `hyperref`'s `\autoref` method to create cross-references, be sure to issue the directive

```
\def\photoautorefname{Snímek}
```

after loading `hyperref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,demo]{article} 
\usepackage[english, czech]{babel} 
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tocloft} 
\tocloftpagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{float} 
\newfloat{photo}{htbp}{lop}
\floatname{photo}{Snímek}
\newcommand\listofphotos{\listof{photo}{Obrazové přílohy (fotodokumentace)}}

\usepackage[numbib,nottoc]{tocbibind} 
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}    
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[photo]{singlelinecheck=false, 
                     justification=RaggedRight}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % omit 'demo' option in real document

\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks=true,allcolors=black]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listofphotos 

\section{Introduction}

\begin{photo}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=14cm]{picturefile} 
\caption{Pohled pod stolovou desku -- před restaurováním} 
\end{photo}

\begin{photo}
\includegraphics[width=15cm]{picturefile} 
\caption{Detail stolové desky -- před restaurováním} 
\end{photo}

\end{document}
```